# group list of dictionaries python by value

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
init list =[
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 30,"city":"Washington"},
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 30,"city":"Washington"},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 20,"city":"las palmas"},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 54,"city":"las vigas"},
  {"name": "mila", "age": 87,"city":"las palmas"},
  {"name": "maylo", "age": 46,"city":"las palmas"},
  {"name": "milanie", "age": 30,"city":"las palmas"}
]
```

and I want to convert it to something like this:

```
final_list= [{"city":"las palmas",
              "count":4,
              "names":[
                  {"name": "milanie", "age": 30,"repeated":1},
                  {"name": "maylo", "age": 46,"repeated":1},
                  {"name": "mila", "age": 87,"repeated":1},
                  {"name": "Mark", "age": 20,"repeated":1}]},
             {"city":"las vigas",
              "count":1,
              "names":[
                  {"name": "Pam", "age": 54,"repeated":1}]},
             {"city":"Washington",
              "count":2,
              "names":[
                  {"name": "Tom", "age": 30,"repeated":2}]}
]
```

I already used panda to group them by `city`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this 
`my_final_list = pd.DataFrame(init_list).groupby(['city']).agg(
        count=('city', 'count')).reset_index().to_dict('records')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas solution

```
# encoding: utf-8
import pandas as pd

init_list = [
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 30,"city":"Washington"},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 20,"city":"las palmas"},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 54,"city":"las vigas"},
  {"name": "mila", "age": 87,"city":"las palmas"},
  {"name": "maylo", "age": 46,"city":"las palmas"},
  {"name": "milanie", "age": 30,"city":"las palmas"}
]

# use python pandas to group by city
count = pd.DataFrame(init_list).groupby("city")
final_list = []
for city, group in count:
    records = group.to_dict("records")
    for r in records:
        r.pop("city")

    final_list.append({"city": city,
                       "count": len(group),
                       "names": records})

print(final_list)
```

Comment: how can I get the count of each name

Comment: `len(group)`   @salahmazroai

Comment: `len(group)` is the count of each city can you check the `len(group)` I have changed the input

Comment: found it I used pandas group on the records, thank you

Comment: My pleasure. @salahmazroai

Answer (score 0):

solution without pandas

```
# encoding: utf-8
init_list = [
  {"name": "Tom", "age": 30,"city":"Washington"},
  {"name": "Mark", "age": 20,"city":"las palmas"},
  {"name": "Pam", "age": 54,"city":"las vigas"},
  {"name": "mila", "age": 87,"city":"las palmas"},
  {"name": "maylo", "age": 46,"city":"las palmas"},
  {"name": "milanie", "age": 30,"city":"las palmas"}
]

# group by city to get a new list
def group_by_city(list_of_dicts):
    final_list = []
    for i in list_of_dicts:
        if i["city"] in [x["city"] for x in final_list]:
            for j in final_list:
                if i["city"] == j["city"]:
                    j["count"] += 1
                    j["names"].append({"name":i['name'], "age":i['age']})
        else:
            final_list.append({"city":i["city"], "count":1, "names":[{"name":i['name'], "age":i['age']}]})
    return final_list


res = group_by_city(init_list)

print(res)
```

Comment: I used  pandas to avoid the nested loops

Comment: and get the repetition